# What does прокачать mean

Tags: узус, сленг

I looked for it in dictionaries, but it doesn't seem to be a standard verb, except in a few cases where it means to run someones name through the police systems. Perhaps it's slang?

очень хочу **прокачать** мои знания по английскому

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, it's slang. **Качать** means pump. This word (by my opinion) came from bodybuilders, who **pump** theirs muscles. Today this word got wide meaning as improve something. *Прокачать игрового персонажа в Wow.* - pump my hero in WoW. Phrase in question mead "I really want to improve my English skills".

Comment: Yeah, right. You can also translate it as "to level up", "to train". Though, it is strictly colloquial, i.e. you are going to see this word ("качать", "прокачать", "прокачка") used a lot in game communities but never as an official term used in the game itself (unless the game itself is easy on meta-jokes).

Answer (score 0):

Literally "Pump up", but it's used as "Upgrade", "Increase" or "Improve".